# Writing a script to set current time depending on which cell the image is in

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

I have a setup of buttons in my "A" Column on my sheet that when pressed, log a value into the "F" column of the current time. However, each of these buttons is an individual image with their own customized function hardcoded to each row in the "F" column i.e. :

```
`function recordTombF2 () {
  var thisSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var range = thisSpreadSheet.getRange("F2");
  range.setValue(recordTime())
}

function recordTombF3 () {
 var thisSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var range = thisSpreadSheet.getRange("F3");
 range.setValue(recordTime())
}`
```

etc etc.

Since images can't be inside cells and function as buttons, the buttons just hover over empty cells in the "A" column to give the appearance of staying the same when the sheet is sorted.

Is there any way to make my functions to log the time generic? I have to write a new recordTombF(?) whenever I add a new row and I just wanted 1 function to log time.

Comment: You could use Insert Image in cell.  Then when you click the cell you could use onSelectionChange to get the cell address that was clicked.  Use offset to set the time in column F.

Comment: How important is it to have an image in Column A as the “trigger”. Seems like a case of form over substance.

Comment: The question does not show the `recordTime()` function. If it contains anything other than `return new Date()` please show it.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use [checkboxes](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7684717) instead of images as buttons. To do that, select the pertinent cells in column `A`, choose **Insert > Checkbox** and replace your current code with the following:

```js
'use strict';

/**
* Simple trigger that runs each time the user manually edits the spreadsheet.
*
* @param {Object} e The onEdit() event object.
*/
function onEdit(e) {
  if (!e) {
    throw new Error(
      'Please do not run the onEdit(e) function in the script editor window. '
      + 'It runs automatically when you hand edit the spreadsheet. '
      + 'See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63851123/13045193.'
    );
  }
  recordTomb_(e);
}


/**
* Writes a timestamp in column F when a checkbox is ticked
* in column A.
*
* @param {Object} e The onEdit() event object.
*/
function recordTomb_(e) {
  //  - see https://stackoverflow.com/q/77710918/13045193
  try {
    const parameters = [

      ////////////////////////////////
      // [START modifiable parameters]
      {
        sheetsToWatch: /^(.+)$/i,
        sheetsToExclude: /^(Excluded|AnotherExcluded)$/i,
        columnToWatch: 1, // column A
        valueToWatch: 'TRUE',
        columnToStampOffset: 5, // column F
        stampFormat: 'yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss',
      },
      // [END modifiable parameters]
      ////////////////////////////////

    ];
    let sheet, sheetName;
    const settings = parameters.find(p =>
      p.columnToWatch === e.range.columnStart
      && p.valueToWatch === e.value
      && (sheetName = sheetName || (sheet = sheet || e.range.getSheet()).getName()).match(p.sheetsToWatch)
      && (!p.sheetsToExclude || !sheetName.match(p.sheetsToExclude))
    );
    if (!settings) {
      return;
    }
    e.range.offset(0, settings.columnToStampOffset)
      .setValue(new Date())
      .setNumberFormat(settings.stampFormat);
    e.range.setValue(false);
  } catch (error) {
    e.source.toast(`${error.message} ${error.stack}`, 'Error in recordTomb_()', 30);
    throw error;
  }
}
```

The script will run automatically when you tick a checkbox in column `A`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using `onSelectionChange(e)` to simulate a button click.  I have placed an image of a button in each cell.  Then I create an `onSelectionChange(e)` trigger to detect which cell has been clicked.  You may have to close and reopen the spreadsheet for the trigger to become active.

Although the event object for `onSelectionChange` isn't described in the documentation by using `JSON.stringify(e)` you will see it has a `source` and `range` property similar to `onEdit`.

[image]

**Code.gs**

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  if( e.range.getSheet().getName() === "Test" ) {
    if( e.range.getColumn() === 1 ) {
      if( e.range.getRow() < 6 ) {
        let now = new Date();
        now = Utilities.formatDate(now,"PST","hh:mm:ss")
        e.range.offset(0,5).setValue(now);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Reference**

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/)
- [Event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)